# Perl sharing variables between threads compilation error

Tags: multithreading, perl, shared-memory

I think i shouldn't be getting this error, but since I am getting it, I am obviously wrong.
The situation is very simple: Share one variable between N threads and have them increment it by one.

The code is pretty short and straight forward:

```
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use strict;

sub Handler()
{
    my $shared_var : shared = 1000;
    my @threads; 
    push @threads, thread->new(\&PrintGreeting);
    $_->join for @threads;
}

sub PrintGreeting()
{
    $shared_var++;
    print "hello, world $shared_var \n";
}

Handler();
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Global symbol "$shared_var" requires explicit package name at /home/path/tosource/program.pl line 15.
```

Line 15 is the line where I increment the variable.

I searched, but I couldn't find someone with the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you are using threads doesn't mean the rest of Perl's rules are thrown out of the window.

You define `my $shared_var` in `Handler` but try to use it in `PrintGreeting`. That wouldn't work with a normal variable and it won't work with one shared between threads either. Basic variable scoping.

Perhaps you meant to decalre a package-level (global) variable instead?

Comment: I see. Well I will move them to the global scope.